# How can I break a long equation?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

Upon compiling, one of my equations extends out of my column width in my final output. Options I tried--

1. `breqn` package asks for `expl3.sty` file which the compiler is unable to locate, (would have been the easiest way in the `{dmath}` environment
2. `//` in the equation,
3. `{split}`, `{multiline}` environment of `amsmath` but none of the 3 approaches seem to work.

Any tip from your Texperience(!)?

PS: I use latest version of TexnicCenter (+MikTeX 2.9) and the equation is in the `{equation}` environment right now.

Comment: MikTeX should automatically install expl3. If not, you can always add it via its package manager.

Comment: TeXnicCenter (TXC) has difficulties with automatic package installation. See [MiKTeX 2.9 Issues](http://miktex.org/2.9/issues) for the details and a possible remedy.

Comment: I find it odd that `//` did not work. Are you perhaps using `\[ \]` for this equation in which case you can't use `//`?

Comment: maybe it is because the correct syntax is `\\ ` ?

Answer (score 4):

> none of the 3 approaches seem to work

That is a bad sentence. Do you get any errors?

Here is an example of the documentation of amsmath with `split`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}
\begin{split}
 H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
     \sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
    &\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
      \Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: A split equation using amsmath]

Comment: Thanks everyone,have been struggling with it for almost 2 days now, but no success yet. Here are the results of your kind suggestions:@caramdir The pckge mgr shws an eror whle installing expl3 "Unknown archive file size", @Thorsten I am afraid I do not see how to change "MikTex Options",@Peter Yup, // doesn't work, could you pls explain what do you mean by...\[ \] for this equation...?@Werner The problem/error I face when I use `split` is that no pdf output is created. Also for some mysterious reason my error output window has disappeared and can't get it via tools>wind>cmpl reslt. Cheers

Comment: @Thorsten posted a [comment about "Unknown archive file size" of the `expl3` package update using MiKTeX Package Manager](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=14183) suggesting that you *Syncronize* your repository. See/try his answer at the bottom of the link provided.

Comment: @Abhimanyu: Did you include the `amsmath` package (for `split`, etc.)?

Comment: Is there any way to put the reference number at the bottom of the equation?

Comment: @MOLi: Yes. Therefore you don't need the environment `split`. You can work with `align` and `\notag`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/in-align-environment-how-can-you-label-some-but-not-all-of-the-equations/26426#26426

Answer (score 1):

This at least compiles and produces output.  Removed the extra closing brace in `\usepackage{breqn}}` and the extra `\` in `\end{\equation}`, and commented out the `\begin{comment}`, `\end{comment}` blocks.  Plus I think you had some extra blank lines that I removed, and I think the `quad` was intended to be `\quad`. Hope this gets you going...

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{breqn}
%-------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%this equation 1 is ok
    \begin{equation}
        g\left[Pr(happy_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}+\alpha_{1}.\left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\epsilon_{im}
        \label{Original}
    \end{equation}
%this equation 2 is ok
\begin{equation}
        g\left[Pr(happy_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}+\alpha_{1}.\left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\beta.{year}+\epsilon_{im}
        \label{yearlytrend}
    \end{equation}


%to split3
%have commented it out as no pdf output is produced otherwise
%\begin{comment}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        g\left[Pr(happy_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}+\alpha_{1}.
            \left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\\
        \quad+\beta.{year}+\gamma.region.
            \left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\delta{region}+\epsilon_{im}
        \label{region}
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
%\end{comment}

%again no output produced when {dmath} environment of breqn used; commented out
%\begin{comment}
%to split4
\begin{dmath}
g\left[Pr(happy_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}+\alpha_{1}.\left|
    living\_shock_{im}\right|+\beta.{year}+//+\gamma.demo_{iy}.\left|
    living\_shock_{im}\right|+\delta_{iy}.demo_{iy}+\epsilon_{im}
    \label{demo}
\end{dmath}
%\end{comment}

%to split5
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        g\left[Pr(happy_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}+\alpha_{1}.\left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\beta.{year}+\gamma_{1}.demo_{iy}.\\
\left|living\_shock_{im}\right|+\gamma_{2}.urbanpop\%_{iy}.\left|living\_shock_{im}    \right|+\delta_{1}.demo_{iy}+\delta_{2}.urbanpop\%_{iy}+\delta_{3}.population+\epsilon_{im}
        \label{size}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```