# In align environment, how can you label some (but not all) of the equations?

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I know that the align environment labels all the lines, while the align* environment labels none of the lines. Is there a way to have the align environment label only some of the lines?

For example, suppose I have something like this:

```
\begin{align}
x+y 
\\
x-y 
\\
xy
\end{align}
```

This labels all three lines. Is there a way to only label, say, the second line (x-y)?

Comment: Related question: [Suppress equation number when not refered to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/suppress-equation-number-when-not-refered-to)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the command `\notag`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x+y 
\notag\\
x-y 
\\
xy
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
You can also use the command `\nonumber` (see comment)

**EDIT:**
If you want to tag only one equation you can use `\tag`. In the following example I combine the command `\tag` with `\refstepcounter`  to create the command `\tageq`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\tageq{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x+y 
\\
x-y \tageq\label{1}
\\
xy
\end{align*}

\ref{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For standard LaTeX math environments you can also use `\nonumber`, but `amsmath` is recommended which uses `\notag`. There is also `\tag{<label>}` which allows you to set any other text instead of the number.

Comment: You need to `\notag` the third line as well...

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful! One question I still have though is, if I only want to tag one equation out of many, is there a way to do it without using `\notag` a bunch of times? Is there a way to use `\tag` in an `align*` environment but to have it follow the numbering of the document?

Comment: @Alan C: I edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 y &= x+y \\
 y &= x-y \label{1} \\
 y &= xy
\end{align}

See Eqn.~\refeq{1} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]