# only number some condition in conditional function

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, cases

Thanks to the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases), however, is it possible that I only number some of the conditions instead all?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [In `align` environment, how can you label some (but not all) of the equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26425/5764)

Comment: no so much to be clear I need the conditional equation

Comment: Different environment, same solution.

Comment: sure, of course, everything is kind of duplicate with certain level of abstraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{f(x)=}
   1 & $x>0$ \label{positive}   \\
   0 & $x=0$ \notag             \\ % <-- not numbered case, you also can use \nonumber
  -1 & $x<0$ \label{negative}
\end{numcases}

See \eqref{positive} or the \eqref{negative} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]