# Using Align environment with partial numbering

Tags: numbering, align

The following will produce 3 lines numbered (1), (2) and (3) on the right:

```
\begin{align}
x = 1\\
y = 1\\ 
z = x + y    
\end{align}
```

while using `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`
will produce the same lines without numbers.

What if I want to produce the same three lines but with only the last one numbered, or only the first and second lines numbered, etc ?

Comment: use `\tag` and `\notag`.

Comment: I don't know where to fit them inside or outside begin{align} environments. Please give a sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26426/106804) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/106804) and knowing about `\notag` from `amsmath` you can have:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\tageq{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x = 1\\ 
y = 1\\ 
z = x + y   \notag 
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
x = 1\\ 
y = 1\\  \tageq
z = x + y   
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```