# line breaking has no effect in doublespace

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am trying to break a `doublespace` content without any success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent \(\left\{\left\{ aaa \right\},
\\ ~ \\ ~ \\ ~ \\
\left\{bbb\right\}\right\}\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

The part `{bbb}` does not go to the new line as if `\\` has no effect in `doublespace`

Comment: this is not because of `doublespace` but because of iniline math

Comment: @touhami, how can i fix it?

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239252/what-is-the-difference-between-split-multline-align-breqn-for-breakin and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/how-can-i-break-a-long-equation

Comment: @touhami, thanks but using `split` and `align` also gave me error

Comment: @touhami, I used `\begin{equation}
\begin{split}` and now the problem is fixed.